# How to link Youtube data's (duration & current time) to a slider bar?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, slider, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to create my own Youtube controle bar with Youtube-API. It works great. 
However, I have some troubles to link youtube player data's (Duration & Current Time : [Youtube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr#Retrieving_video_information) ) to my slider bar ([MDL slider](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section/))

The selector stay at the middle of the bar slider...

Could someone help ?

Thanks,

Marc

HTML

```
<input class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range" id="s0" min="0" max="???" value="???" step="1">
```

JS

```
<script>
$("#s0").attr({
   "max" : var player=$('#video').data('ytPlayer').player; player.getDuration():;
   "value" : var player=$('#video').data('ytPlayer').player; player.getCurrentTime():;
});
</script>
```

Comment: the js is a bit wrong, there is a :; at the end and the element after : are not wrapped in {}

Comment: I've juste change my JS :

    <script>       
     function setCursor() {
            $("#s0").attr({
                                  "max" : function(){ var player=$('#video').data('ytPlayer').player; return player.getDuration(); },
                                  "value" : function(){ var player=$('#video').data('ytPlayer').player; return player.getCurrentTime(); }
                               });
        console.log("1 second");
        setTimeout(setCursor, 1000);
    }
    </script>

But the result don't change